How can I keep multiple rows of data while only displaying one row, but the others show up when moused over or selected?
Basically, we have a rickhouse full of barrels. Each rick/slot  is 3 levels/rows high. We have 180 ricks/slots, or 540 levels/rows. Each row is 10 barrels deep. So each barrel has a rick number, a level number, and a space number. So each barrel (say, #2201) is represented by a descriptor like "54-2-9"
We'd like to not have to have 540 rows of cells to display barrel locations. We were wondering if there was a way to display the 180 ricks but have them expand to all 3 levels of that rick when selected, without "hiding" the other two rows, then un-hiding them when we want to access them. That way, each space would represent a barrel location, and would contain the barrel number (#2201, for instance)
    Slots                                   

Rick #  Row 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   EXPAND
2-3 2201    2202    11  2204    2205    2206    2207    2208    2209    2210
2-2 3107    3108    3109    3110    3111    3112    3113    3114    3115    3116
2-exp   2-1 1423    1424    1425    2001    1427    1428    1429    4004    1431    1432
3   EXPAND
4   EXPAND
5   EXPAND
6   EXPAND
7   EXPAND
8   EXPAND
etc
In above layout (sorry for wonky formatting, row 2 is expanded to 3 sub-rows, 2-1, 2-2, & 2-3

You can use the SelectionChange event handler to change the row height of a selected cell. Assuming that the full information is displayed in two lines, I propose the following code (placed in the sheet module):
Dim prevrow As Long
Const OneRow = 18.5      ‘ row height of a single row

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target(1), Range("C3:D4")) Is Nothing Then
        If prevrow <> 0 Then Rows(prevrow).RowHeight = OneRow
        prevrow = 0
    ElseIf Target(1).Row <> prevrow Then
        If prevrow <> 0 Then Rows(prevrow).RowHeight = OneRow
        Target(1).RowHeight = 2 * OneRow
        prevrow = Target(1).Row
    End If
End Sub


The code responds to the change in selection, not to moving the mouse over the cell.
The second attempt to understand what is going on.
I still don't know where these numbers come from. I assume that they will be entered as array constants in subsequent cells of one column (in the example it is column C, cells C1:C10, I filled only C2 and C6). Entries for a single column must be quoted texts, including 3 numbers each, separated by Alt+Enter or CHAR(10). Column separators according to the language version of Excel.
Code to handle the Worksheet_SelectionChange event:
Dim prevrow As Long
Const OneRow = 18.5

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target(1), Range("C1:C10").Resize(, 10)) Is Nothing Then
        If prevrow <> 0 Then
            Rows(prevrow).RowHeight = OneRow
            Cells(prevrow, "C").NumberFormat = ";;;""EXPAND"""
            Cells(prevrow, "D").Resize(, 9).NumberFormat = ";;;"
            prevrow = 0
        End If
    ElseIf Target(1).Row <> prevrow Then
        If prevrow <> 0 Then
            Rows(prevrow).RowHeight = OneRow
            Cells(prevrow, "C").NumberFormat = ";;;""EXPAND"""
            Cells(prevrow, "D").Resize(, 9).NumberFormat = ";;;"
        End If
        Target(1).RowHeight = 3 * OneRow
        Cells(Target(1).Row, "C").Resize(, 10).NumberFormat = "General"
        prevrow = Target(1).Row
    End If
End Sub

The word "EXPAND" is only displayed in column C. This is done by changing the format code.

File to download

Sorry, should have been more clear in explaining the goal. Idea is sheet would have 180 rows, corresponding to the 180 numbered vertical ricks/slots (54, 102, etc). Each row/slot would have 10 columns (cells) corresponding to the 10 barrel slots (6, 9, etc.) but when a row is activated (selected), that row would pop up 3 rows for the 3 vertical rows associated with that particular rick (slot). Then each of those cells would get the corresponding barrel # associated with that position entered (#2204, etc).

Show how it would look like on a worksheet when the cell is active/inactive, because I can't imagine based on this description.

Not sure how to post an image - it's a PNG

Edit your original post and add an image.

I need a 10 reputation to add an image - if I paste cells from a spreadsheet, is there a way to keep formatting?

That's a lot closer but I'm not sure I understand what you did to get there. I'm a noob when it comes to code. Maybe think of it as 180 bookcases lined up next to each other, with only their spines showing out, each numbered 1-180. Each bookcase has 3 shelves, and each shelf 10 slots for books. So 54-2-7 would indicate a position 7  on shelf 2 of bookcase 54, and the cell for that spot would contain a barrel number. So when you selected one of the bookcases, it would expand to show all 30 spaces (3 shelves). Then de-select it to collapse it back to just the "spines".

But where does the data come from, and what is the end goal? If you know the bookcase number, shelf number, and book position on the shelf, why display the contents of all the other shelves?
